# Silhouette value after normalizing a variable and re-clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, k-medoids

I have a non-normalized variable and other normalized variables and I make a clustering with k medoids (or k means).
If I let the first variable non-normalized, I get better results in terms of average silhouette coefficient.
If I normalize it, I get worse results. I know that if the variable doesn't get normalized then it's like to give a "weight" to the variable.
I'd ask if an high average silhouette coefficient means a better clustering whether I normalize or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You *cannot* compare numbers you get with different normalization. It's apples and oranges.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you but I invite you to read the following document, near page 26: https://publications.csiro.au/rpr/download?pid=csiro:EP137756&dsid=DS3

Comment: I don't see where they compare Silhouettes with different normalization; and silhouette did not work well for them: the clusters did not exhibit a good silhouette. **The k they chose had a very *bad* silhouette**; and clearly they chose their parameter *not* based on the silhouette...

Comment: I mean that variable transformations are applied and also weights are applied. Transformations and weights are not the same for each variable.

Comment: And this changes silhouette values in a way that makes the scores before and after transformation not comparable. Only compare scores of different clusterings on the exact same preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Majority of *internal clustering criterions* (including here average Silhouette value, I suppose) are suited to compare different cluster solutions (different *number of clusters* and/or clustering *method*) of the *same* data.

Some clustering criterions will tolerate arbitrary *(dis)similarity measure* which a clustering method operates with or which it implies behind the scene (if any); but others require just specific measures - typically euclidean distance. And a few criterions may impose their own (dis)similarity measure at their computation.

Very few, if any, clustering criterions have been so wisely standardized that they allow direct comparison among cluster solutions obtained on *different datasets* (be that different objects to cluster or different features). So, don't decide which cluster partition is better, A or B, if different data are involved in them.

*Standardizing/normalizing* of features, of all or selected, as well as other *transformations* with data, change data. Dimensions get "distorted" unequally. It is like another dataset what appears then. So, see the previous paragraph.

---

Here is an immediate and untested, one possible heuristic approach to conclude if a partition **c1** based on cluster analysis of data first transformed **t1** (or, maybe it means no transformation: raw data) is better or worse than a partition **c2** based on cluster analysis of the data first transformed **t2**.

You have clustering index (e.g. average Silhouette) values: $I_{t1c1}$, $I_{t2c2}$. Instead of direct comparing $I_{t1c1} - I_{t2c2}$, calculate two more values, now *without* doing cluster analyses:

- $I_{c1t2}$ - t2-transtorm the original data and compute the index
  value for c1 against it.
- $I_{c2t1}$ - t1-transtorm the original data and compute the index value for c2 against it.

Note that we can directly compare $I_{t1c1}$ with $I_{c2t1}$, and $I_{t2c2}$ with $I_{c1t2}$ - because transform **t** (i.e. the data values) within both cases is the same. Compute product $(I_{t1c1}-I_{c2t1})(I_{c1t2}-I_{t2c2})$. If solution **c1** pretends to be definitely better than solution **c2**, it should show itself to be better both under t1 and t2, its overall advantage being the product of the two local advantages. Assuming that index I is "the greater is the better", - if both multipliers are positive **c1** is better, if both are negative **c2** is better. If the product is negative, no definite conclusion.